# Counting a cycle

Tags: java, algorithm, interview-questions, hash-map

An interview question I got -

> Each element of an `int` array points to the another element,
>   eventually creating a cycle. Starting at `array[0]`, find the length
>   of the cycle.
>
> **Examples**:
>
> Input:
>
> ```
> array = [1, 0]
> ```
>
> Output:
>
> ```
> 2
> ```
>
> Input:
>
> ```
> array = [1, 2, 1]
> ```
>
> Output:
>
> ```
> 2
> ```
>
> Note how element 3 is not part of the cycle
>
> Input:
>
> ```
> array = [1, 3, 0, 4, 1]
> ```
>
> Output:
>
> ```
> 3
> ```
>
> Note how element 0 is used to find the cycle, but is not part of the
>   cycle count.

**Constraints:**

- Must be in Java 7
- Elements will always be positive or 0 and never point outside the array
- Elements will never point to themselves
- There will always be a cycle
- The cycle will be at least length 2

**My Code:**

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

//Time Complexity: O(n) (worst case)
//Space Complexity: O(n) (worst case)
class CycleDetector{
    private Map<Integer, Integer> visitedElements = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    private int counter = 0;

    public int countCycle(int[] array){
        int startOfLoop = visitNextElement(array, array[0]);
        return counter - startOfLoop;
    }

    private int visitNextElement(int[] array, int e){
        counter++;

        Integer startOfLoop = visitedElements.put(e, counter);
        if(startOfLoop == null){
            return visitNextElement(array, array[e]);
        }
        else{
            return startOfLoop;
        }
    }
}
```

I also had an alternative idea where instead of have a `Map<int int>` I would just have a `Set<int>`. In this case when I found the cycle I would just go back to the start of the cycle and re-run it (but this time with a counter). This would trade speed for memory, but both would still technically be O(n). I ultimately decided against this because if you scale this up to arrays that are not of `int`s, the solution I wrote would do better (since the extra memory is ints, where as the extra computations could be complex).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is neat, and it is easy to follow the logic through.

On the other hand, I am confused by two things.

1. Your class needs to be instantiated, but it is not reusable. After calling `countCycles(...)` the instance is 'burned'. Why don't you use static methods, or create an instance for each run?
2. The data structure you use for storing the path taken so far is relatively expensive. I would have used a parallel int-array for that. As you loop through the data you add the count to the parallel array at the matching index.

So, I would have written:

```
public static int countCycles(int[] data) {
    int[] counters = new int[data.length];
    int index = 0;
    int count = 0;
    while(counters[index] == 0) {
        counters[index] = count++;
        index = data[index];
    }
    return count - counters[index];
}
```

That essentially does the same task as yours, but uses an array instead of a Map, and it thus removes all the autoboxing and other overhead.

The drawback here is that it always uses the worst-case \$O(n)\$ space (even though that is likely significantly less than the average case for the `HashMap` in terms of absolute space. Each entry in the `HashMap` is about 96 bytes or more, whereas the array above is simply 4 bytes per entry.

This got me thinking, and i realized we can do the whole thing in \$O(n)\$ time, and \$O(1)\$ space if you can reuse the space that's given as input. If you store the count as a negative value, then you can put that in to the input array, and not allocate any other space:

```
public static int countCyclesBurn(int[] data) {
    int index = 0;
    int count = 0;
    while(data[index] >= 0) {
        int tmp = data[index];
        data[index] = -(++count);
        index = tmp;
    }
    return count + data[index] + 1;
}
```

The above will overwrite the relevant cells in the data array with the count at that time. This will be the fastest system, but comes at the expense of corrupting the input data. If that is permitted, then that's fine.

Comment: Negative counts! Thats brilliant!. Also would statics work? If it was static, then the `Map` would be polluted the next time you run it. I guess we can solve this by just cleaning up at the end, but it seems like a weird thing to do. Also if I use your negative counts idea then the issue doesn't even come up

Comment: @DavidGrinberg Using static is nearly always wrong. Cleaning up afterwards is not thread-safe. Simply create an instance and wrap the whole code in a single static method. ++ Corrupting the input is fine when heavy optimizations are needed, otherwise I'd avoid it (something will break one day someone decides to reuse the input array elsewhere).

Comment: Note that you can do this with 1/32th the space using a bitset and two passes. If you don't want to mutate input, this is a good trade-off space-wise.

Answer (score 2):

It is a classic problem; it can be done in constant space and linear time. First, find an element belonging to the loop:

```
find_loop
    slow = 0
    fast = 0
    do
       slow = next(slow)
       fast = next(fast)
       fast = next(fast)
    while slow != fast
    return slow
```

The index returned belongs to the loop. Now you may find the loop length:

```
count_loop_length(index)
    length = 0
    cursor = index
    do
        cursor = next(cursor)
        length += 1
    while cursor != index
    return length
```